# LINQ query with double sequental Select and GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of `EmployeeInfo` objects, that I want to build a table from and group Employees by `Country` and `Department`. I need to group List of EmployeeInfo by Country and then in each grouped List group them by Department and process each List.

I have tried a lot of ways, but didn't get it working.

I tried something like this:

```
public class EmployeeInfoToTableDataSetTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<List<EmployeeInfo>,                                          
                                                        List<TableDataSet>>
{
    public List<TableDataSet> Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return
            (from EmployeeInfo in ((List<EmployeeInfo>)(context.SourceValue))
             group EmployeeInfo by EmployeeInfo.Country
                 into EmployeeInfos
                 select //Here I would need to "select" EmployeeInfo from EmployeeInfos 
                 group by EmployeeInfo.Department - but it does not work like this
                   new TableDataSet()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to get you started:

```
var groupedList = ((List<EmployeeInfo>)(context.SourceValue)).
   GroupBy(x => x.Country).
   ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.
       GroupBy(y => y.Department));
```